# How to add input check in a Linq Query to build XML only if input is valid

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an input value that I need to use to  build out an XML. Only if the value exists, do I need to build the sub-elements.

Example

```
string classInput="something";     
XDocument classes = new XDocument(
                     new XElement("Classes",
                                         new XElement("Class",
                                                 new XElement("Name", classInput))
                                                ));
```

returns what I want:

```
<Classes>
  <Class>
    <Name>something</Name>
  </Class>
</Classes>
```

However, the query above returns:

```
<Classes>
  <Class>
    <Name></Name>
  </Class>
</Classes>
```

in the case classInput is null or empty, but I want it build the sub-XML only if classInput is a non-empty string. i.e In the above case, I would just like to build out:

`<Classes />` if, say classInput = "";

Tried to add a check in the query, but then it processes the string classInput character wise, instead of as a string. Then I get

```
 <Classes>
      <Class>
        <Name>something</Name>
      </Class>
    </Classes>
```

I have some more inputs that I have to build some more sub-elements in the same way, so I need a solution that can be extensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the input with a [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and return null if the input is null or empty:

```
XDocument classes = new XDocument(
                      new XElement("Classes", String.IsNullOrEmpty(classInput) ?
                          null :
                          new XElement("Class",
                              new XElement("Name", classInput))
                    ));
```